# Error 1822 failed to add the foreign key constraint hosp_patient_deptname_fk

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints, mysql-workbench

I'm currently working on this table. I'm getting constraint errors for the table hosp_patient but everything else works. The error reads Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'hosp_patient_deptname_fk' in the referenced table 'hosp_department'
Here is the sql code

```
USE user;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hosp_department;
CREATE TABLE hosp_department
(
    dept_number     INT         PRIMARY KEY,
    dept_name       VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL              ,
    dept_location   VARCHAR(20)                           ,
    dept_authorization VARCHAR(20)
);



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hosp_employee;
CREATE TABLE hosp_employee
(
    emp_id  INT     PRIMARY KEY     AUTO_INCREMENT,
    emp_fname       VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    emp_mname       VARCHAR(20),
    emp_lname       VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    emp_ssn         INT(9)                  ,
    emp_salary      INT             NOT NULL,
    emp_city        VARCHAR(50)             ,
    emp_state       VARCHAR(50)             ,
    emp_zip         INT                     ,
    emp_supervisor_id   INT                 ,
    emp_department_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT hosp_employee_supervisor_fk FOREIGN KEY (emp_supervisor_id) 
    REFERENCES hosp_employee(emp_id),
    CONSTRAINT hosp_employee_department_fk FOREIGN KEY (emp_department_id) REFERENCES 
    hosp_department(dept_number)
);



-- hosp_patient
-- need to fix last constraint

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hosp_patient;
CREATE TABLE hosp_patient
(
    patient_id      INT         PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    patient_fname   VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL              ,
    patient_mname   VARCHAR(20)                           ,
    patient_lname   VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL              , 
    patient_dob     INT                                   ,
    patient_sex     CHAR(1)                               ,
    patient_floornumber INT                               , 
    patient_deptname    VARCHAR(20)                       ,
    CONSTRAINT hosp_patient_floornumber_fk FOREIGN KEY (patient_floornumber) 
    REFERENCES hosp_department(dept_number),
    CONSTRAINT hosp_patient_deptname_fk FOREIGN KEY (patient_deptname)
    REFERENCES hosp_department(dept_name)
); 



SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you've defined a foreign key constraint to a non-primary-key column in the referenced table.  The PK of table `hosp_department` is `dept_number`, not `dept_name`.

Keep in mind that a foreign key *must reference a unique row in the referenced table.*  Nothing in the schema stops you from assigning the same department name to two different department IDs;  if that occurs, then the DB engine cannot know which department a patient actually refers to.

Some DBMS's (MS-SQL Server for one) allow you to create a FK to a *UNIQUE* field in the referenced table.  In other words, you could create a FK to `hosp_department.dept_name` if you defined a UNIQUE constraint on that column, or if you defined a UNIQUE index on the column.  I don't know if MySQL permits this or not, but IMO it's very bad practice either way.

FK's need to refer to primary keys in a good DB design unless there is a very good (and very unusual) reason otherwise.  So, you should rethink this entire schema.  Cheers.

Comment: MySQL does permit an FK referencing any key of the referenced table. _"InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are the first columns in the same order."_ Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: InnoDB even allows referencing a non-unique index of the referenced table, but this is non-standard and leads to odd effects, like possibly referencing more than one row in the referenced table. I recommend do not try to do this!